# how to debug getSkuDetails when getting developer error 5

Tags: android, debugging, in-app-billing

As far as I understood in IAB v3 it is required that the APK is published, if not life at least in the Alpha channel.

I'm getting an BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR (5), when calling getSkuDetails.
As this is my first-time implementation of in-app billing, I really need to debug to know how it works, what I'm getting back, and write code according to the results.

But if the APK is required to be published to get some results from getSkuDetails, how I am suppose to debug, test, and write code at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that one of the reasons for "Developer Error 5" is wrong data passed to getSkuDetails() - in my case we were passing a list with 6 elements but the last one was an empty string.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me this week, and lost me a solid 2 days while trying to figure things out. I am so thankful you posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the developer account instead of a tester gmail account